# Очередь запросов

Tags: многопоточность, php

Подскажите, если ли решения для такой задачи. Есть очередь заданий

- url1 proxy1
- url2 proxy2
- url3 proxy1
- url4 proxy2

Как можно сделать очередь заданий, чтоб каждый запрос был не чаще 5 сек, например, если Url2 завис, чтоб задачи 1 и 3 не выполнились одновременно. Пробовал сервер очереди gearman. Решение этой проблемы там не смог реализовать. Какие еще есть варианты?

Язык php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил вопрос через сервер очереди gearman

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параллельность cURL'а: см. пример к [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) Вашему скрипту придётся мониторить "здоровье" каждой из проксей.

Upd. под "мониторить" подразумевается следить за тем, как давно завершился предыдущий запрос через эту прокси - сравнивать timestamp'ы

Comment: curl_multi не подходит. 
мониторить прокси не нужно т.к. прокси свои. а вот мультикурл не подойдет потому что там невозможно проконтролировать очередь запросов на конкретный прокси.
например мы послали очередь 10 урлов на 5 прокси, какой-то урлов быстрей вернул результат, какой-то задержал..идет смещение очередности и вероятность что 3-4 запроса подряд пойдут на один прокси.

Comment: @artur, а Вы уверены, что подобную задачу удобно делать на пхп?

Comment: нужно какой-то сервер очереди и обращаться к нему через пхп)

Comment: отчего же curl_multi не подходит? В первом комментарии к [curl_multi_select](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) приведён пример перебора хэндлов в процессе обработки. А перед отправкой на исполнение пачки задач вы запоминаете какой хэндл с какой прокси ассоциирован.